# Derived System.Data classes

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, multiple-inheritance, .net

I would like to utilize classes that inherit the System.Data name space.

Specifically, I would like to have classes CarColumn, CarTable, and CarSet derived from DataColumn, DataTable, and Dataset respectively.

I would like to be able to add additional properities to each class.  As an example this is how I would like to reference items within the classes:

> CarSet.CarTable(0).Columns(0).foo
>
> CarSet.CarTable(0).bar

I know that VB.Net is not capable of Multi-Inheritance.  What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can achieve what you want in an easy way. I believe you'll have to subclass CarColumn, CarDataRow, CarTable, and CarDataSet individually (and probably a CarDataView/CarDataRowView in there somewhere as well).

Is there any chance you can use another design, perhaps LINQ?